# Does Docker normally fail to clean up its iptables rules?

Tags: iptables, docker, port-forwarding, alpine-linux, docker-compose

I'm on Alpine Linux 3.13.2, iptables-1.8.6-r0, and docker-20.10.3-r0.

I'm trying out Graylog 4 using their sample docker-compose .yml file. I got Graylog running as expected, then did `docker-compose ... down`, so I could start customizing the config. And that's when the problems started. But, even if I *didn't* change the config, the next `docker-compose ... up -d`, would result in the web UI's connection timing out. My eventual workaround was simply to change all the port-forwards every time I bounced the containers (E.g. 9000:9000 became 9001:9000, then 9002:9000, etc.).

Ultimately, after a LOT of research, I discovered that old the port-forwarding rules that Docker setup in the *nat* table on the *DOCKER* chain were not being deleted after a `docker-compose ... down`. (FYI: **All** the rules pertaining to previous instances remain.) So what I did was use *iptables-save*, edit the saved file to delete the old rules, then apply my edits with *iptables-restore*. After that, I could connect to the Graylog UI again, without needing to change the ports or bounce the containers.

**So the meat of the question is:** Is this expected Docker behavior or a bug?  FYI: The most I see logged at "/var/log/docker.log" is a warning that my Linux instance doesn't have "ip6tables".

I presently expect that my new workaround will be to see how I can tell Docker to statically assign internal IP addresses for my containers.

## Tangent

And hopefully this will also happen to "fix" the other problem I have at reboot where docker experiences one of those

> iptables failed:  ...  Another app is currently holding the xtables lock. Perhaps you want to use the -w option?\n (exit status 4))

errors and fails to start up my graylog container. Because maybe all those rules it leaves behind are triggering a race condition somehow?

Comment: Someone else appears to have the same-ish root problem: https://github.com/pterodactyl/panel/issues/3088

Comment: And [another one](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/7637).  I've gone ahead and attempted to submit [a bug report](https://github.com/distribution/distribution/issues/3376), so hopefully we'll find out if it's truly a bug or it's some known/by-design behavior that I somehow should have known about.

Comment: I've been directed from the distribution/distribution repo over to the **moby/moby** repo, where I found that [someone has already submitted a bug report for this exact situation](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/42029). So we'll see how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution For Now;

```
/etc/docker/daemon.json
```

```
{
  "ipv6" : false
}
```

Comment: I had to create an `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file, but it totally worked. If I "down" my docker-compose config, docker actually cleans up the `nat` table now.